# How to Customize the Layout (height and Width), and containership of layouts?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I have created a `TableLayout` with two rows where first row has one `TextView` and second row has  two columns, first one has a `ListView` and the second one has one `EditText` and a `Button` each in different rows. I want both rows of equal height (exactly half of the screen) and both of the columns of second row should be of equal width (exactly half of the screen). I Want to build something like this: [image]

How should I proceed ? Which layout I should choose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think your current solution will work(because of the requirement for equal space(width and height) + the `ListView` presence). One solution is to use nested `weights`(which are bad for performance, but(probably, without knowing what you do) not something that important that will break your app) like in the layout below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/identical_layout" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </ListView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="ddd" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>




</LinearLayout>
```

Another option to avoid the nested `weights` problem is to use a `RelativeLayout` like below(I haven't tested it):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/included_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/identical_layout" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/included_layout" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/anchor"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_above="@id/anchor"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="#99cc00"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/anchor" >

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/list"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" >
            </ListView>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="ddd" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The `identical_layout` layout file represents the common layout shared by your `Activities`.

Comment: +1000 thanks You are really awesome, Presently I was trying to achieve this with TableLayout, However your answer made it easire for me,  I am trying to implement the first option... and if their is some performance overhead I will surely go for the second approach... Thanks once again...

Comment: that worked... Now the only problem is ListView doesn't scroll, How can I do that??? once again thanks a billion...

Comment: @anDroider I don't know why your `ListView` doesn't scroll. There is something related to your code and not the above layout files as I tested them right now and the `ListView` works as expected..

Comment: It works for the first time but if once focus reaches EditText, ListView wont scroll after that...

Comment: I am using the same code as mentioned in your answer..(the nested weights) for illustrations purpose I have set some sample String values (like random names of my colleagues), everything works fine (all thanks to you)... However once the focus enters in the last LinearLayout, After that the ListView won't scroll even if I click on it multiple times... I am testing it on emulator for API 2.3.3 (10)...

Comment: @anDroider There is something on your code. I've tested the layout (using the default layout file `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` for the `ListView`) and there is NOTHING that prevents the `ListView` from being able to scroll(I've tested this on 2.2 and 2.3). I don't know other stuff to recommend, maybe try the second layout and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: Its working fine in device (Samsung Galaxy), thanks...  the same code works well... I had already used `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` while creating ListView's ArrayAdapter but it was not scrolling in emulator. All izz well that ends well, thankfully I tested it on device and it works like charm... thanks