# View with 0height and 0width isn't hidden

Tags: android, tablerow

Sorry for my bad english. I've a table row and i've set the first view with record's code. I've set this view with 0px height and 0px width. But it takes me half screen! Why? Where is the mistake?

This is the code:

```
        try{

        txtId= new TextView(this);
        imgCategory= new ImageView(this);
        txtDescrizione= new TextView(this);
        txtDataFine= new TextView(this);
        imgPriorita= new ImageView(this);

        txtId.setText(id);
        txtId.setWidth(0);
        txtId.setHeight(0);
        txtId.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
        txtId.setTextSize(1);


        if(priorita.equalsIgnoreCase("3")){
            imgPriorita.setImageResource(R.drawable.todo_priority_3);}
        else if(priorita.equalsIgnoreCase("2")){
            imgPriorita.setImageResource(R.drawable.todo_priority_2);}
        else if(priorita.equalsIgnoreCase("1")){
            imgPriorita.setImageResource(R.drawable.todo_priority_1);}

        imgPriorita.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        imgPriorita.setMaxWidth(widthDisplay/10);
        imgPriorita.setMaxHeight(40);
        imgPriorita.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);


        txtDescrizione.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        //txtDescrizione.setText(Html.fromHtml("<i>"+descrizione+"</i>"));
        txtDescrizione.setText(descrizione);
        txtDescrizione.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
        txtDescrizione.setWidth(widthDisplay/5);
        txtDescrizione.setHeight(40);
        txtDescrizione.setTextSize(12);
        //setto la descrizione su una sola riga e con true fino a quando ci stanno le lettere
        txtDescrizione.setSingleLine(true);
        txtDescrizione.setLines(1);


        txtDataFine.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        txtDataFine.setText(data.getDateTimeTodo(dataFine));
        txtDataFine.setWidth(widthDisplay/5);
        txtDataFine.setHeight(40);
        txtDataFine.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
        txtDataFine.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        txtDataFine.setTextSize(12);

        if(category.equalsIgnoreCase("2")){
            imgCategory.setImageResource(R.drawable.todo_category_2);}
        else if(category.equalsIgnoreCase("1")){
            imgCategory.setImageResource(R.drawable.todo_category_1);}
        else if(category.equalsIgnoreCase("3")){
            imgCategory.setImageResource(R.drawable.todo_category_3);}
        else if(category.equalsIgnoreCase("5")){
            imgCategory.setImageResource(R.drawable.todo_category_5);}
        else if(category.equalsIgnoreCase("4")){
            imgCategory.setImageResource(R.drawable.todo_category_4);}
        else if(category.equalsIgnoreCase("6")){
            imgCategory.setImageResource(R.drawable.todo_category_6);}



        imgCategory.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
        imgCategory.setMaxWidth(widthDisplay/5);
        imgCategory.setMaxHeight(40);
        imgCategory.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);

        rowTodo[counterBackground]= new TableRow(this); 
        if((counterBackground%2)==0){
            rowTodo[counterBackground].setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.greyListCp));}
        else{
            rowTodo[counterBackground].setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));}

        rowTodo[counterBackground].setMinimumHeight(heightRowTodo);
        idRow_gl=Integer.parseInt(id);
        rowTodo[counterBackground].setId(idRow_gl);

        rowTodo[counterBackground].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view_cliccata) {
                    onclickRow(view_cliccata);
            }   
        });


        imgAnagraficaTodo[counterBackground]=new ImageView(this);

        if(id_anagTodo.equals("")){}
        else{   
            imgAnagraficaTodo[counterBackground].setImageResource(R.drawable.toanag);
            imgAnagraficaTodo[counterBackground].setPadding(20, 3, 0, 0);
            imgAnagraficaTodo[counterBackground].setMinimumWidth(widthDisplay/5);
            imgAnagraficaTodo[counterBackground].setMaxHeight(40);
            imgAnagraficaTodo[counterBackground].setId(idRow_gl);
            imgAnagraficaTodo[counterBackground].setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);

            imgAnagraficaTodo[counterBackground].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view_cliccata) {
                        Data.myHashMapVar.put("ID_TODO", view_cliccata.getId());
                        onclickImgAnagraficaTodo(view_cliccata,id_anagTodo);
                }   
            });
            arrList_AnagTodo.add(id_anagTodo);
        }

        rowTodo[counterBackground].addView(txtId);
        rowTodo[counterBackground].addView(imgPriorita);
        rowTodo[counterBackground].addView(txtDescrizione);
        rowTodo[counterBackground].addView(txtDataFine);
        rowTodo[counterBackground].addView(imgCategory);
        rowTodo[counterBackground].addView(imgAnagraficaTodo[counterBackground]);


        List_TodoList.addView(rowTodo[counterBackground]);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

And heightDisplay and widthDisplay are set in this way:

```
display=getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
             heightDisplay=display.getHeight();
             widthDisplay=display.getWidth();
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wan't it gone. why not just use

```
txtId.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

?

Comment: But as @marmor wrote, you should really declare your layouts in the xml. And only when creating stuff genericly you could be forced to do it in code.

Comment: I've already declared it @_@. I've declared tablelayout in my xml, I only add row by code... :)

Comment: I can't create my table row by row in xml because i grab record dinamically from db

Comment: you should create the row layout in another xml, and in the code you'll inflate it, put the data in it, and add it to the table. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2685130/819355

Comment: And maybe consider using a listview/listactivity and use adapter. Makes code much more consistently and readable

Comment: can you explain it anders please?

Comment: Sounds to me like you wan't to display a decent amount of data... Like a list of countries, or fruits in this example:
http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/

Answer (score 1):

You should really really really consider working with layout xml instead of code for your screen designs, check this tutorial for more info:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html

Regarding your problem, I'd suggest using [visibility](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility%28int%29) instead of changing width/height:

```
txtId.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```